# Angular JS ng-selected with ng-repeat not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to set ng-selected true in ng-repet 
my HTML :

```
    <select ng-model="editActivities.NewArea">
       <option  ng-repeat="area in areas" value="{{area.ID}}" ng-selected="editActivities.Area.ID==area.ID">{{area.Name}}</option>
    </select>
```

the areas object:

```
{Name : "City1", ID : "1"}
{Name : "City2", ID : "2"}
{Name : "City3", ID : "3"}
```

the value of editActivities.Area.ID is 2.

when i print the values in editActivities.Area.ID and in area.ID its print :

```
1 2 , 2 2 , 2 3
```

and still the city2 is not selected.

also i Notice that the selected option is :

```
<option value="? undefined:undefined ?"></option>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using ng-selected you should set the model value, that is set `$scope.editActivities.NewArea=2` in your controller. Basically when there is model binded to dropdown it will ignore the ng-seleted first time. If you remove ng-model from select tag, default value will come.
Try the following plunker.

without ng-model - https://plnkr.co/edit/0Mj1LHhJgkrluWGQLdBn?p=preview

with ng-mdoel - https://plnkr.co/edit/89PqDYdbfrGwUOHLIGMU?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Based on the details of your question your controller code looks something like:

```
$scope.areas = [{
  Name: "City1",
  ID: "1"
}, {
  Name: "City2",
  ID: "2"
}, {
  Name: "City3",
  ID: "3"
}];

$scope.editActivities = {
  Area: {
    ID: "2"
  },
  NewArea: "2"
};
```

That being the case, you can simply use the ng-options directive and let the ng-model binding handle the initial selection, like this:

```
<select ng-model="editActivities.NewArea" ng-options="area.ID as area.Name for area in areas">
```

Here's a working [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/1egKyrLO3WVTsKxnTCbI?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You should just use ng-options:

```
<select ng-model="editActivities.NewArea" ng-options="area as area.Name for area in areas">
</select>
```

And as usual, the model is the single point of truth in angular. So the selected option is the one stored in `editActivities.NewArea`.
So if you want the first area to be selected, use something like this in your controller:

```
$scope.editActivities = {
    NewArea: $scope.areas[0]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do change your ng-selected to the following; there's a comparsion statement('==') instead of assignment('=')

```
ng-selected="editActivities.Area.ID=area.ID"
```